# How can I print out the time initialized by user input?

Tags: c++, chatbot

Im new to coding in general and particularly to C++. Im trying to make something like google assistant, but text based, and am currently working on printing out the time when the user types in something like "timepls". I am using an arraybased kind of library for the code, so that I store preconfigured strings inside an array and compare the user input variable to each object in each array. and if the string matches with one of the arrays in the function, it gets executed. My problem is, that I have tried ctime and used the same initialisation code as with another function which I know works (its the only other function lol). Can someone help me to print out the current time with user input?
Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void howareyouq();
void whattimeisit();



    
int main(){
   howareyouq();
   whattimeisit();
}
           
           
           

void howareyouq(){
    string howruq[4] = {"how are you?", "hru?", "how r u?", "hru"}; //array for the valid thingies
    string user_input; //creating userinput variable
    cin >> user_input; //writing user input to user_input 
    for (int i=0; i!=4; i++) { 
        if (user_input == howruq[i]) {  //if the array contains something equal to user_input, this gets executed
            cout << "Thanks, Im fine!" << endl; //the answer
        }
    }
}

void whattimeisit()
{
    string thetimepls[] = {"timepls", "what time is it?", "how late is it?", "whats the time?", "time?"};
    string user_input;
    cin >> user_input;
    for (int i=0; i++;) {
        if (user_input == thetimepls[i]) {
            time_t now = time(0);
            char *date = ctime(& now);

            cout << "The local date and time : " << date << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this line carefully: `for (int i=0; i++;) {`

Comment: (Side Note: you should probably ask for input once, and then send that input to each function which could handle it. They way you've written it you need to write something for `howareyouq` before you can ask for the time.)

Comment: the problem is that if I ask for the input in main(), I will have to declare the string in main too. but if I do, and then call one of the functions, the string gets reset. also I thought of this too and made the line exactly the same as in the other function, didnt work tho.

Comment: in main read in a string -> then send that string (as a const ref) to each function. Have each function _not_ read in a string, just used the passed in parameter.

Comment: but if I make it a const, I couldnt continue the "conversation" with the bot, right? sry if I say something stupid

Comment: Depends on how you want to do that. I've added an answer with the suggested fixes. You'll have to consider how you want to turn that into a conversation going forward (maybe return from a function if you want to replace the input string??)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the bounds right and reading in a single time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void howareyouq(string const& user_input);
void whattimeisit(string const& user_input);

int main()
{
    string user_input; //creating userinput variable
    cin >> user_input; //writing user input to user_input 

   howareyouq(user_input);
   whattimeisit(user_input);
}          

void howareyouq(string const& user_input)
{
    string howruq[4] = {"how are you?", "hru?", "how r u?", "hru"}; //array for the valid thingies
    for (int i=0; i!=4; i++)
    { 
        if (user_input == howruq[i]) {  //if the array contains something equal to user_input, this gets executed
            cout << "Thanks, Im fine!" << endl; //the answer
        }
    }
}

void whattimeisit(string const& user_input)
{
    string thetimepls[] = {"timepls", "what time is it?", "how late is it?", "whats the time?", "time?"};
    for (int i=0; i!=5; i++) { 
        if (user_input == thetimepls[i]) {
            time_t now = time(0);
            char *date = ctime(& now);
            cout << "The local date and time : " << date << endl;
        }
    }
}
```